# Python OpenCV - как найти центр фигуры

Tags: python, opencv

Нужно найти центр объекта и совершить по этой точке клик (OpenCV python)

```
res = cv.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    x = (pt[0])
    y = (pt[1])
    pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

Comment: Мне кажется можно тупо взять среднее арифметическое x и среднее арифметическое y по всем точкам фигуры. А так то фигура может быть самой причудливой формы, кто знает, где у неё вообще центр.

Comment: https://www.learnopencv.com/find-center-of-blob-centroid-using-opencv-cpp-python/

Comment: Как правило это всегда прямоугольник или квадрат